# Is BulkCopy available for SQL-Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, bcp

Is BulkCopy still supported by SQL-Server 2012?

Comment: Yes, you can use BulkCopy in sql 2012 **and** windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **BCP.EXE** for SQL Server 2012 works on Windows 10. I have tried it myself several times, though do not use it extensively (so there *could* be a minor issue with one of the features that I haven't used, but I highly doubt it).

Also, BCP (like the other command-line utilities) is freely available, so you should test it for yourself on your system(s). You can download it from the following page:

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065)

Expand the "**Install Instructions**" section and scroll down to (or search for) "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Command Line Utilities".